# Subscribe to topic cordova-plugin-fcm giving error "TypeError: Object(...) is not a function"

Tags: ionic4

I want to allow user to subscribe to  topics, So if a user login to application I want the user to subscribe to that topic and receive notification. but whenever I try this method I get error

```js
import {
  FCM
} from '@ionic-native/fcm/ngx';
import {
  Platform
} from 'ionic-angular';


constructor(private fcm: FCM, public platform: Platform) {}

this.tenentId = "1"

if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
  this.fcm.subscribeToTopic('tenant-');
  this.fcm.getToken().then(token => {
    alert("token is " + this.tenentId);
  })
}
```

This is the error i am facing when I run "ionic cordova run android"

[image]

Please help with the issue i am stuck very badly in this

Answer (score 2):

Downgrade your FCM version `"@ionic-native/fcm": "^5.+"` to `"@ionic-native/fcm": "^4.20.0"`

Run these command after uninstalling FCM "^5.+"

`ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated

npm install @ionic-native/fcm@4.20.0`

and Import it

`import { FCM } from '@ionic-native/fcm';`

Answer (score 1):

This error is due to @ionicnative/fcm. You must downgrade it to version 4.